# How to implement single connection between objects in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

In my Qt app I have many windows, and sometimes they need a "Back" button. This button is placed on `ToolBar` component in the `header` of the `ApplicationWindow` .

What I want to achieve, is that this `Back` button, would have only single connection to other objects , i.e. the connection to the last object that called `connect` method. Right now with every `connect` I am getting a new connection and when the signal is emitted, it is called multiple times. Unfortunately Qt doesn'thave `disconnectAll` method, if it would , that would have solve my problem , I would just call `disconnectAll` before and then `connect` and that would implement single connection.

So , how are you doing this functionality in Qt , with a simple method?

Here is a minimal reproducible example, click on the tabs many times, then press 'Back' button and you will see lots of `console.log` messages. And what I need is this message to correspond to the last object that is connected to the `Back` button.

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Tabs")
    signal back_btn_clicked()

    SwipeView {
        id: swipeView
        anchors.fill: parent
        currentIndex: tabBar.currentIndex

        Page1Form {
            id: page1
            function page1_callback() {
                console.log("page 1 back button triggered")
            }
            function install_button() {
                enable_back_button(page1_callback)
            }
        }
        Page2Form {
            id: page2
            function page2_callback() {
                console.log("page 2 back button triggered")
            }
            function install_button() {

                enable_back_button(page2_callback)
            }
        }
        function install_back_button(idx) {
            if (idx===0) {
                page1.install_button()
            }
            if (idx===1) {
                page2.install_button()
            }
        }
    }
    Button {
        id: btn_back
        visible: false
        text: "Back Button"
        onClicked: back_btn_clicked()
    }

    footer: TabBar {
        id: tabBar
        currentIndex: swipeView.currentIndex

        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("Page 1")
            onClicked: swipeView.install_back_button(0)
        }
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("Page 2")
            onClicked: swipeView.install_back_button(1)
        }
    }
    function enable_back_button(func_name) {
        btn_back.visible=true
        back_btn_clicked.connect(func_name)

    }
}
```

PageForm.ui is defined like this

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

Page {
    width: 600
    height: 400

    header: Label {
        text: qsTr("Page 1")
        font.pixelSize: Qt.application.font.pixelSize * 2
        padding: 10
    }

    Label {
        text: qsTr("You are on Page 1.")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You are providing your code, your own wrong solution and ask how to fix it. Provide a problem, and ask how to achieve a specific goal.

Comment: @folibis I already explained the problem: Qt doesn't implement single connection between objects, and the goal is to have this functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest hack, I think, would be to store the callback in a property, then in `enable_back_button()`, reference that property in your `disconnect()` function, and update the property accordingly with the new callback passed as a function argument. (*The rationale for this argument being that the `disconnect()` function must take in an argument: the slot to disconnect. So we'll need to keep track of it some way or another.*)

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    // ... omitted for brevity

    property var prevCallback: null

    // ... ofb


    function enable_back_button(func_name) {
        btn_back.visible=true

        if (prevCallback)
            back_btn_clicked.disconnect(prevCallback)   // disconnect previous callback

        back_btn_clicked.connect(func_name)  // connect new callback

        prevCallback = func_name  // update property with new callback
    }
}
```

And this could work on multiple connections as well, by simply changing the storage into an array, then iterating through that.

Comment: I already unsuccessfully tried it, but didn't know function types can be held in `var` type. Works perfectly. Thanks!